# How to Add a Newline (\n) Character to String in Jess

Tags: string, character, special-characters, jess

Assuming I have a string called `?a` with a value of `"b"`, how can I add a newline character to it so that it will contain the value `"b\n"`?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
(bind ?a (str-cat ?a \n))
(bind ?a (str-cat ?a crlf))
(bind ?a (sym-cat ?a \n))
(bind ?a (sym-cat ?a crlf))
```

The only method I know to make this work is below, but I'm wondering if there is any other way that makes the code more readable.

```
(bind ?a (str-cat ?a "
")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a variable containing the \n:

```
(bind ?newline "
")
```

and then use it in str-cat or sym-car or other places.

```
(bind ?a (sym-cat ?a ?newline))
```